# Cuál es la diferencia entre ..density.. y ..count../sum(..count..) en un histograma en R

Tags: r

Estaba realizando un curso de datacamp sobre la representación en un histograma y me he encontrado con las siguientes representaciones:

```
ggplot(adult, aes (x = SRAGE_P, fill= factor(RBMI))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), position="fill", binwidth = 1) +
  BMI_fill


ggplot(adult, aes (x = SRAGE_P, fill= factor(RBMI))) +  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position="fill",binwidth = 1) + BMI_fill
```

En el curso me indican lo siguiente sobre la primera representación:

> This is not an accurate representation, as density calculates the
>   proportion across category, and not across bin.

Entiendo la última representación, pues es el porcentaje por edad de cada clase, pero no entiendo qué operación realiza en el primero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es exactamente lo que mencionan en el curso. La estética `..density..` establece el tamaño para cada parte de la barra en función de:

- El valor de `x` para el `bin` en particular
- ponderado en función de los totales generales de cada categoría `RBMI`

Veamos un ejemplo, vamos a achicar un poco el `data.frame` original para dejar solo tres edades: 18, 50 y 84, simplemente para poder apreciar mejor las diferencias:

```
adult %>%
    filter(SRAGE_P  %in% c(18,50,84)) %>% # Filtramos las edades que nos interesan
    select(RBMI, SRAGE_P) -> new.adult    # Dejamos solo las dos columnas que necesitamos

str(new.adult)

'data.frame':   1653 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ RBMI   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Under-weight",..: 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ SRAGE_P: num  50 50 50 50 84 50 18 18 84 50 ...
```

Si hacemos el histograma de estos datos usando `..density..`

```
ggplot(new.adult, aes (x = SRAGE_P, fill= factor(RBMI))) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), position="fill", binwidth = 10) +
    BMI_fill
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vemos las tres barras correspondientes a las tres edades, lo que ocurre con este gráfico, es que debemos "leerlo" de una forma un poco antinatural, hay que leerlo "horizontalmente", tomemos el caso de la categoría `Under-weight`, lo que nos dice esta gráfica es que del total de los `Under-weight` más de la mitad esta en los adultos de 18 años y que la menor cantidad está en los adultos de 50. Si lo leyéramos "verticalmente", podríamos suponer que la mitad o más de los adultos de 18 años están debajo del peso normal, cuando en realidad no ocurre esto. Si vemos el gráfico de la otra forma:

```
ggplot(new.adult, aes (x = SRAGE_P, fill= factor(RBMI))) +  
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)), position="fill",binwidth = 10) + 
    BMI_fill
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vemos ahora sí, que la cantidad de jóvenes de 18 de bajo peso es mínima. En esta gráfica, efectivamente las superficies para cada categoría en cada barra o `bin` son proporcionales a las cantidades de casos de cada categoría dentro del `bin`

Para confirmar este comportamiento con los datos, primero necesitamos los totales de cada categoría:

```
new.adult %>%
    group_by(RBMI) %>%               # Agrupamos todos los RBMI
    summarize(t_RBMI = n()) %>%      # Contamos los casos de cada grupo
    ungroup() -> totales_categorias

totales_categorias

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  RBMI           t_RBMI
  <fct>           <int>
1 Under-weight       57
2 Healthy-weight    807
3 Over-weight       502
4 Obese             287
```

De las 1653 observaciones, vemos como se distribuyen por cada categoría, si estos totales los agregamos a los grupos de `RBMI` y `SRAGE_P`

```
new.adult %>%
    group_by(RBMI, SRAGE_P) %>%         # Agrupamos todos los RBMI y SRAGE_P
    summarize(t_SRAGE_P = n()) %>%      # Contamos casos para cada grupo
    left_join(totales_categorias) %>%   # Join con los totales de RBMI
    mutate(perc=t_SRAGE_P/t_RBMI) %>%   # Calculamos porc. sobre el total de RBMI
    arrange(RBMI, SRAGE_P)              # Ordenamos

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   RBMI [4]
   RBMI           SRAGE_P t_SRAGE_P t_RBMI  perc
   <fct>            <dbl>     <int>  <int> <dbl>
 1 Under-weight        18        30     57 0.526
 2 Under-weight        50        13     57 0.228
 3 Under-weight        84        14     57 0.246
 4 Healthy-weight      18       254    807 0.315
 5 Healthy-weight      50       347    807 0.430
 6 Healthy-weight      84       206    807 0.255
 7 Over-weight         18        80    502 0.159
 8 Over-weight         50       301    502 0.600
 9 Over-weight         84       121    502 0.241
10 Obese               18        52    287 0.181
11 Obese               50       196    287 0.683
12 Obese               84        39    287 0.136
```

Vemos ahora sí que la categoría `Under-weight` se distribuye más del 50% entre los menores de 18, es decir, 30 casos sobre un total de 57, esto es lo que muestra `..density..`. Sin embargo, esos 30 es una proporción mucho más pequeña sobre todos los casos de los adultos de 18 años, que es lo que muestra `..count../sum(..count..)`.

#### Algo que me faltó aclarar

El porcentaje mostrado en los datos anteriores, dan una idea de como funcionaría `..density..`, pero no son los porcentajes finales que se usa para cada área de cada barra, estos luego deben ser escalados según su tamaño en relación al total. La demostración viendo los datos es un poco más compleja y larga:

```
new.adult %>%
    group_by(RBMI) %>%
    summarize(t_RBMI = n()) %>% 
    ungroup() -> totales_categorias

new.adult %>%
    group_by(SRAGE_P) %>%
    summarize(t_SRAGE_P = n()) %>% 
    ungroup() -> totales_edades

new.adult %>%
    group_by(RBMI, SRAGE_P) %>%
    summarize(c_SRAGE_P = n()) %>%
    left_join(totales_categorias, by = "RBMI") %>%
    left_join(totales_edades, by = "SRAGE_P") %>%
    mutate(perc1=c_SRAGE_P/t_RBMI) %>%
    mutate(perc2=c_SRAGE_P/t_SRAGE_P) %>%
    arrange(SRAGE_P, RBMI) %>%
    ungroup() -> final

final %>% 
    left_join(final %>% 
                group_by(SRAGE_P) %>%
                summarize(t_perc1 = sum(perc1)),
              by = "SRAGE_P") %>% 
    mutate(perc1=perc1/t_perc1) %>% 
    select(RBMI, SRAGE_P, perc1, perc2)
```

Y ahora sí, `perc1` y `perc2` representan en porcentaje, el tamaño de cada area (`fill`) de cada una de las barras, el primero corresponde a `..density..`  y el segundo a `..count../sum(..count..)`

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   RBMI           SRAGE_P perc1  perc2
   <fct>            <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Under-weight        18 0.445 0.0721
 2 Healthy-weight      18 0.266 0.611 
 3 Over-weight         18 0.135 0.192 
 4 Obese               18 0.153 0.125 
 5 Under-weight        50 0.118 0.0152
 6 Healthy-weight      50 0.222 0.405 
 7 Over-weight         50 0.309 0.351 
 8 Obese               50 0.352 0.229 
 9 Under-weight        84 0.280 0.0368
10 Healthy-weight      84 0.291 0.542 
11 Over-weight         84 0.275 0.318 
12 Obese               84 0.155 0.103
```

Comment: Perfectamente aclarado, gracias!